# How can I connect to another database in an API made with nodejs, express, sequelize, mysql and jsqonwebtoken?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am making an API for some queries to a database, each user must first access with their credentials and a token is generated to perform the process, this works correctly, however, each user has their database in different directions, I have a central database that contains the user table and another table that has the connection data to their respective database, The API currently makes the login, brings me the connection data and assign it to a global variable for later in a middelware reassign the connection to the database but I have not managed to work correctly, it gives me errors and does not connect to the new database, what do you recommend me to do?

what do you recommend me to do?

This my login code:

```
// Acá hacemos el login del usuario
async function login(req, res) {
    const { nombre, password } = req.body;
    
    // Buscar el usuario en la base de datos por correo electrónico
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { nombre } });

    // Si el usuario no se encuentra, retornar un error
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Credenciales inválidas' });
    }

    // Comparar la contraseña proporcionada con la contraseña almacenada en la base de datos
    const passwordMatches = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    // Si la contraseña no coincide, retornar un error
    if (!passwordMatches) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Credenciales inválidas' });
    }

    // Generar un token JWT para el usuario autenticado
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, jwtConfig.secret);

    // Si el usuario es correcto y hace login, consultamos la tabla de empresa para traer los datos de conexión
    const lnIdUsuario = user.id_empresa;

    // Creamos un objeto con los detalles de conexi+ón obtenidos de la base de datos de usuarios
    try {
        // Consultamos la tabla de empresas para obetener los datos de conexión
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({ where: { id: lnIdUsuario } });

        if (!lnIdUsuario) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid company ID' });
        }

        // Eliminar esto
        console.log(profile.dbname_empresa);
        console.log(profile.ip_empresa);
        // Hasta acá eliminar
        //Fin parte para traer los datos de conexión de cada usuario
        global.configFile = {
            database: profile.dbname_empresa,
            username: 'dbName',
            password: profile.dbpw_empresa,
            host: profile.ip_empresa,
            port: profile.port_empresa,
            dialect: 'mysql'
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error.'});
    }
    
    res.json({ token });
    req.session.internalToken = token;
}
```

Here below I leave my middelware so that after logging in it connects to the database of each user:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require('../config/database.js');

function switchDatabase(req, res, next) {
    const credentials = { // obtain user's credentials from the request
        database: global.configFile.database,
        username: global.configFile.username,
        password: global.configFile.password,
        host: global.configFile.host,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        port: global.configFile.port
        // any other necessary options
    };
    const newConnection = new sequelize(credentials);

    // replace the existing Sequelize instance with the new one
    req.app.set('sequelize', newConnection);

    next();
}
```